# Sum array properties into a new array

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with properties like:

```
myCosts {
 monthlyCost: {
   currency: EUR,
   amount: 10,
 },
weeklyCosts: {
   currency: EUR,
   amount: 100,
 }
}
```

I need to create a new object/array which will have the same type and properties just the amount will be a sum of myCosts.monthlyCost.amount + myCosts.weeklyCosts.amount.

So it will be like:

```
sumCosts {
  monthlyCosts: {
    currency: EUR,
    amount: 110
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it add up to 410 if it's _weekly_ costs?

Comment: why do you need monthly cost in result?

Comment: check my solution below

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not using an array but an object.

You can still utilize [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to get the desired output.

```
const myCosts = {
 monthlyCost: {
   currency: 'EUR',
   amount: 10,
 },
 weeklyCosts: {
   currency: 'EUR',
   amount: 100,
 }
};

const result = Object.entries(myCosts)
    .reduce((acc, [curKey, curValue]) => {      
      if(curKey.localeCompare('amount')) {    
        acc.montlyCosts.amount += curValue.amount;
      }
      return acc;
    }, 
    {montlyCosts: {currency: 'EUR', amount: 0}}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function transformCost(myCost) {
   var arr = [...Object.entries(myCost).map((obj)=>obj[1])];
   var sum = arr.reduce((prev,next) => (prev + (next.amount)), 0);
   return {
            monthlyCost: {
                  currency: arr[0].currency,
                  amount: sum
            }
          };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `reduce`

```js
const myCosts = {
  monthlyCost: {
    currency: 'EUR',
    amount: 10,
  },
  weeklyCosts: {
    currency: 'EUR',
    amount: 100,
  },
};

const sumCost = {
  monthlyCosts: {
    currency: 'EUR',
    amount: Object.entries(myCosts).reduce(
      (acc, [, {amount}]) => acc + amount,
      0
    ),
  },
};

console.log(sumCost);
```